# Compress or copy folder to stdout

Tags: directory, compression, stdout

I can't compress folder recursively to stdout. Zip and 7-zip can one file to stdout, but not folder. Rar not compatible compress to stdout in principle. Tar, GZip, Bzip2 - obviously, etc. Please help me find to solution...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to recursively compress the folder (for ex /tmp/222) into stdout (pipe). Can be without compression even (level = 0).